Is a virtual destructor always needed if there are virtual functions?
Is a virtual destructor always needed if there are virtual functions? I was told at the interview that there is no, although everywhere they write that it is necessary. What do you think about this?

it is really not about what people think, having a virtual destructor is required if you delete the object through a pointer to base, if you do that then you need a virtual destructor, and if you don't do that then you don't need a virtual destructor, it has nothing to do with having other virtual functions, and having other virtual functions doesn't affect this criteria

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c35-a-base-class-destructor-should-be-either-public-and-virtual-or-protected-and-non-virtual

The connection is that if you have no virtual functions, you are unlikely to use the type polymorphically, and then also unlikely to need a virtual destructor. But it is not a 1:1 relation.
